# I can't solve this set of equations

Tags: equation-solving, assumptions

I am having trouble solving a set of equations using *Mathematica* 8. I do not get any errors, but I don't get any solutions either.

My parameters and variables are real and non-negative.
`g` is a known, positive constant which I define earlier in my notebook.
Also, I have some restrictions on my parameters and variables in the equations. I've tried to implement these using `$Assumptions` and `Assuming[]`, but it seems like *Mathematica* ignores this.

Here is my code:

```
g:=6.45161;
Solve[{
  u == 1/3 μb - 2/3*e, d == 1/3 μb + 1/3*e, 
  2*(u^2 - (g x/2)^2)^(3/2) - (d^2 - (g x/2)^2)^(3/2) -
     (d^2 - (g y/Sqrt[2])^2)^(3/2) - (e^2)^(3/2) == 0, 
  x >= 0,
  y >= 0,
  μb > e,
  μb >= 0,
  u >= 0,
  d >= 0,
  e >= 0}, {u, d, e}, Reals]
```

`μb` is a parameter and `x` and `y` are variables in some other functions. So what I want is for `u`, `d` and `e` to be functions of `x` and `y`, and dependent of `μb`.

Is there an easy way to solve this in *Mathematica* 8?

Comment: In what way this this fail?  Did you get errors?  Did it run for a long time without a result?

Comment: It runs a long time without a result. I do not get any errors though.

Comment: Unless you have numerical values of `x` and `y` it looks like a pure algebraic solution of this is unlikely.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer. So i probably need to assign values for x and y in a loop and solve theese equations many times and eventually make an InterpolatingFunction for u and d? I know what values x and y should take for different \[Mu]b, so i guess this is an alternative at least. Or do you see a faster or easier way out?